# Continuity and almost everywhere convergence

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, continuity

> **(Folland 2.37)** Suppose that $f_{n}$ and $f$ are measurable complex-valued functions,
>   and $\phi: \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$. If $\phi$ is continuous and
>   $f_{n} \to f$ a.e., then $\phi \circ f_{n} \to \phi \circ f$ almost
>   everywhere.
>
> ***My Proof:***
>
> Since $f_{n} \to f$ a.e. it follows that $$N= \{x: \lim_{n \to \infty}
>  (f_{n} - f) \neq 0 \}$$ is a null set.
>
> Since $\phi$ is continuous, it follows that $\forall \varepsilon >0$,
>   $\exists \delta >0$ s.t. $\forall x$, $\forall f_{k}(x) \in
> > (f_{n}(x))_{n\geq1}$ $$||f_{k}(x) - f(x)|| < \delta \implies || (\phi
> > \circ f_{k})(x) - (\phi \circ f)(x)|| < \varepsilon$$ Now suppose
>   $\exists w$ s.t. $\exists \varepsilon >0$ s.t. $\forall K \in
> > \mathbb{N}$, $\exists k \geq K$ with $|| (\phi \circ f_{k})(x) - (\phi
> > \circ f)(x)|| \geq \varepsilon$.
>
> By continuty of $\phi$ it follows that $\exists \delta > 0$ such that
>   $\forall K \in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists k \geq K$ with $||f_{k}(w) -
> > f(w)|| \geq \delta$.
>
> Thus $w \in N$, and so $\phi \circ f_{n} \to \phi \circ f$ everywhere
>   except on a set of measure zero.

My question is this: I am trying to be very specific with my definition of continuity and limits, and I am not sure if I have been successful. In particular, I am not sure if the section:

> Now suppose $\exists w$ s.t. $\exists \varepsilon >0$ s.t. $\forall K
> > \in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists k \geq K$ with $|| (\phi \circ f_{k})(x) -
> > (\phi \circ f)(x)|| \geq \varepsilon$.
>
> By continuty of $\phi$ it follows that $\exists \delta > 0$ such that
>   $\forall K \in \mathbb{N}$ $\exists k \geq K$ with $||f_{k}(w) -
> > f(w)|| \geq \delta$.

is valid. Any advice on this proof would be useful.

Comment: Which book did you get 'Folland 2.37' from? I tried looking at 'Real Analysis 2nd ed' but it is not the same!

Comment: Ah, never mind! It is exercise 2.37. I thought you meant Theorem 2.37.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really following the notation in your proof. Here is how I would write it:

Suppose $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x) = f(x)$ and let $\varepsilon>0$. By continuity of $\varphi$, we can choose $\delta>0$ such that $|\varphi(f(x))-\varphi (y)|<\varepsilon$ when $|f(x)-y|<\delta$. Then we can choose $N$ such that $n\geqslant N$ implies $|f(x)-f_n(x)|<\delta$. It follows that $$|\varphi(f(x))-\varphi(f_n(x))| < \varepsilon $$
for $n\geqslant N$, as desired.

Comment: Yeah fair enough, your way is much simpler